About Lorentz Invariant
I am reading Schwartz's book, Quantum Field Theory and Standard Model. I have some questions about invariance under Lorentz transformations.

In the book, the scalar fields are functions of space-time that are Lorentz invariant, i.e. under an arbitrary Lorentz transformation, the scalar field does not change:
$\phi(x) \to \phi(x)$. $\ldots$ Take, for example, the temperature of a fluid, which can vary from point to point. If we change reference frames, the labels for the points change, but the temperature at each point stays the same.

If we use the notation $\phi(x^\mu) \to \phi(\Lambda_\mu^\nu x^\mu)$, where $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation, does the invariance mean that
$$\phi(x^\mu) = \tilde{\phi}(x^\mu) = \phi((\Lambda^{-1})_\nu^\mu x^\nu),\forall x^\mu~?$$
The above example makes me confused. Consider space $X=\{a,b\}$, $\phi(a)=1, \phi(b)=2$ and $\tilde{\phi}(a)=2, \tilde{\phi}(b)=1$. Is $\phi =\tilde{\phi}$?

The Lorentz transform of a 4-vector field $V^{\mu}(x)$ in my understanding is
$$V^\mu(x^\eta) \to \Lambda_\nu^\mu V^\nu(\Lambda_\eta^\xi x^\eta),$$
is it correct? Does the invariance mean that
$$\forall x^\eta, V^\mu(x^\eta) = \tilde{V}^\mu(x^\eta) = \Lambda_\nu^\mu V^\nu((\Lambda^{-1})_\xi^\eta x^\xi)~?$$


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It means $\phi(x^\mu) = \tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x}^\mu) = \tilde{\phi}((\Lambda^{-1})_\nu^\mu x^\nu)=\phi(x^\mu)\neq \tilde{\phi}(x^\mu)$
